# Enable html on rails form using formtastic

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I would like to enable html input from user on my form.

Tried: `= f.input :body, :input_html => {:escape => false} and also {:disabled => false}`

Right now the text shows up as a chunk.

if user puts:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text `</br>` of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

should show up as:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
of the printing and typesetting industry.
```

Thank you so much for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

in form `f.text_area`

added method on model

```
def body_enable_html
  body.html_safe
end
```

and called method in views

```
= @collection_page.body_enable_html
```